# Distinguish Between Numbers in String

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm

Say we have two numbers A and B in a concatenated string: AB. How can we distinguish A from B without knowing the lengths of A or B.

As an example, say we have A is the x coordinate and B is the y coordinate. For a grid, we have a file at each gridpoint. So let's we have the files:

```
99059900 = (99.05,99.00)
991010000 = (99.10,100.00)
1000510000 = (100.05,100.00)
100109910 = (100.10,99.00)
99059910 = (99.05,99.10)
991010010 = (99.10,100.10)
1000510010 = (100.05,100.10)
100109910 = (100.10,99.10)
```

In this case, how can we generally find the A and B numbers? The constraint is that the last 2 digits of A and B are separated by some constant value: in the above, A is incremented by 0.05 steps and B is incremented by 0.1 steps.

Comment: you can't... they're not unique: what are the x and y of 111? either use a string separator or fixed width

Comment: will go with @user3080953

Comment: How would you figure it out non-programmatically? Maybe the first one is really 9, 999 ? You must have some rule(s) that you use when you read the file.  Do you have no control over how the file is written?  It seems that this should be changed on the "other" side

Comment: Well, I guess the question is more like this. I have a large number of files in the AB pattern. Each file is corresponds to a point in an xy grid, so the x and y values are evenly spaced. Given a large number of these files can I determine where the delimiter is? The last few digits of A and B will be constant because the spacing is larger than the last few digits of A or B.

Comment: The question is still ambiguous: `1000510000` could still be `(100.05, 100)` or `(10.00, 5100.00)`

Comment: Can you step back and second and really ask your self what you are trying to accomplish by not using a delaminater?  Is this just for theoretical purposes or are you trying to save space?  If it's really about space why not just use a binary file instead of a text file.

Comment: @DanP The files are created from another program and do not have a delimiter. It is black box software so I am not sure how to add the delimiter...

Comment: @user3080953 Yes it is still ambiguous, but I know it can't be (10.00, 5100.00) because the other files are in the vein of (100.00, 99.00). We know the constant spacing. Is their a way I can rigorously use the constant spacing info to differentiate between the two possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Without additional rules, this is an ambiguous task. For the string of length N, there are N-1 possibilities of how you can break it into two non-empty strings.

You said you restrict A to 2 digits, but why? Are the numbers allowed to begin with zero? Do they have a minimum, maximum, or any other property that must be satisfied? Are there any other characters except digits? Are there more strings that you can use as a reference? Unless you have enough constraints, you cannot eliminate this ambiguity.

Comment: Comments are there for asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing at least the length of A or B or both there is no way to figure out what the exact values of A and B are to begin with.  You'll have Length of A + Length of B - 1 possible values for A and B...assuming non negative numbers.  You can probably narrow it down a little more if you assume no numbers have leading zero's as well.

For instance your example of 9999 = (99,99) can come from at least 2 other possibilities.
could have come from

```
9, 999
99, 99
999, 9
```

I would suggest using a tab delaminated values, comma separated values, or some other separator value of your choosing to be able to parse the values back out correctly into their original values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming non-negative integers, here's an algorithm.

To encode A and B into a number:

1. Turn A and B into strings: S = str(A), T = str(B)
2. Left pad the shortest of S and T with zeros so S and T become the same length.
3. U = cooncat("1", S, T)
4. C = int(U)

To decode a number C into numbers A and B:

1. U = str(C)
2. N = (len(U) - 1) / 2
3. A = U[1:N+1] and B = U[N+1:2*N+1]

A Clojure implementation:

```
(defn encode [a b]
  (let [n (max (count (str a))
               (count (str b)))]
    (String/format (str "1%0" n "d%0" n "d")
                   (to-array [a b]))))

(defn decode [c]
  (let [u (str c)
        n (/ (dec (count u)) 2)]
    [(Integer/parseInt (.substring u 1 (inc n)))
     (Integer/parseInt (.substring u (inc n)))]))
```